# ReactJS Bootstrap 5.2: Space Column Elements in NavBar?

Tags: reactjs

I have link items on a footer navbar in a row of columns.

```
import React from "react";
import {Link} from "react-router-dom";

export const NavBarBrandBottom = () => {

    return (
        <div className="container-fluid" style={{
            "justify-content": 'center'
        }}>
            <div classname="row">
                <ul className="navbar-nav mb-lg-0" style={{
                    "font-size": '12px'
                }}>
                    <div className="col">
                        <li className="nav-item me-2">
                            <Link to={"/add"} className="nav-link">
                                <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="16" fill="white"
                                    className="bi bi-plus-square-fill ms-1" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
                                    <path
                                        d="M2 0a2 2 0 0 0-2 2v12a2 2 0 0 0 2 2h12a2 2 0 0 0 2-2V2a2 2 0 0 0-2-2H2zm6.5 4.5v3h3a.5.5 0 0 1 0 1h-3v3a.5.5 0 0 1-1 0v-3h-3a.5.5 0 0 1 0-1h3v-3a.5.5 0 0 1 1 0z"/>
                                </svg>
                                <br/>
                                <span>Add</span>
                            </Link>
                        </li>
                    </div>
                    <div className="col">
                        <li className="nav-item text-center me-2">
                            <Link to={"/tasks"} className="nav-link">
                                <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="16" fill="white"
                                    className="bi bi-card-list ms-1" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
                                    <path
                                        d="M14.5 3a.5.5 0 0 1 .5.5v9a.5.5 0 0 1-.5.5h-13a.5.5 0 0 1-.5-.5v-9a.5.5 0 0 1 .5-.5h13zm-13-1A1.5 1.5 0 0 0 0 3.5v9A1.5 1.5 0 0 0 1.5 14h13a1.5 1.5 0 0 0 1.5-1.5v-9A1.5 1.5 0 0 0 14.5 2h-13z"/>
                                    <path
                                        d="M5 8a.5.5 0 0 1 .5-.5h7a.5.5 0 0 1 0 1h-7A.5.5 0 0 1 5 8zm0-2.5a.5.5 0 0 1 .5-.5h7a.5.5 0 0 1 0 1h-7a.5.5 0 0 1-.5-.5zm0 5a.5.5 0 0 1 .5-.5h7a.5.5 0 0 1 0 1h-7a.5.5 0 0 1-.5-.5zm-1-5a.5.5 0 1 1-1 0 .5.5 0 0 1 1 0zM4 8a.5.5 0 1 1-1 0 .5.5 0 0 1 1 0zm0 2.5a.5.5 0 1 1-1 0 .5.5 0 0 1 1 0z"/>
                                </svg>
                                <br/>
                                <span>Items</span>
                            </Link>
                        </li>
                    </div>
                    <div className="col">
                        <li className="nav-item text-center">
                            <Link to={"/family"} className="nav-link">
                                <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="16" fill="white"
                                    className="bi bi-people-fill ms-1" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
                                    <path
                                        d="M7 14s-1 0-1-1 1-4 5-4 5 3 5 4-1 1-1 1H7Zm4-6a3 3 0 1 0 0-6 3 3 0 0 0 0 6Zm-5.784 6A2.238 2.238 0 0 1 5 13c0-1.355.68-2.75 1.936-3.72A6.325 6.325 0 0 0 5 9c-4 0-5 3-5 4s1 1 1 1h4.216ZM4.5 8a2.5 2.5 0 1 0 0-5 2.5 2.5 0 0 0 0 5Z"/>
                                </svg>
                                <br/>
                                <span>Groups</span>
                            </Link>
                        </li>
                    </div>
                </ul>
            </div>      
        </div>
    );
};
```

When being displayed, these items are all very close to each other - but I want them spaced out evenly over the entire footer, not clustered in the center. What is the best way of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Bootstrap's flex utility classes:

```
import React from "react";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";

export const NavBarBrandBottom = () => {
  return (
    <div className="container-fluid">
      <div className="row">
        <ul
          className="navbar-nav mb-lg-0 d-flex justify-content-around w-100"
          style={{
            "font-size": "12px",
          }}
        >
          <div className="col-auto">
            {/* Add content */}
          </div>
          <div className="col-auto">
            {/* Items content */}
          </div>
          <div className="col-auto">
            {/* Groups content */}
          </div>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
```